# Как получить значение по ключу из строки (String)?

Tags: java, json

Всем доброго времени суток!

После сканирования QR-кода, и раскодирования данных я получаю такую строку (String):

`D/vResult: {"Command":"101","ContractorGUID":"{29545D4D-7AC9-4FCB-9E5C-B7AF4D9A70B5}"}`

Мне необходимо извлечь значение ключа `ContractorGUID`. В данный момент, для этого я использую обрезание строки (`.substring`):

`vResult.substring(35, vResult.length() - 2)`

**Вопрос: Есть ли какое-то более простое решение этой задачи?** Что-то по типу метода `.getString`, как в `JSONObject`.

Comment: Изучите функцию public String[] split(String regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться любой удобной библиотекой работы с JSON и получить результат:

```
String vResult = "{\"Command\":\"101\",\"ContractorGUID\":\"{29545D4D-7AC9-4FCB-9E5C-B7AF4D9A70B5}\"}";
System.out.println("vResult: " + vResult);

try {
    org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser parser = new org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser();
    org.json.simple.JSONObject result = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) parser.parse(vResult);
    String value = (String) result.get("ContractorGUID");
    
    System.out.println("value: " + value);

} catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
```

Консоль:

```
vResult: {"Command":"101","ContractorGUID":"{29545D4D-7AC9-4FCB-9E5C-B7AF4D9A70B5}"}
value: {29545D4D-7AC9-4FCB-9E5C-B7AF4D9A70B5}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] parts = vResult.split("ContractorGUID":"{:", 2);
System.out.println(parts[1]);
```

Comment: При попытке вывести результат в лог `Log.d("vResult", parts[1]);` приложение вылетает с ошибкой java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: Напишите ContractorGUID":"{

Answer (score 0):

Можно регуляркой вытащить:

```
String vResult = "{\"Command\":\"101\",\"ContractorGUID\":\"{29545D4D-7AC9-4FCB-9E5C-B7AF4D9A70B5}\"}";
System.out.println("vResult: " + vResult);

java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^.+ContractorGUID\":\"(\\{.+\\})\"}$");
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(vResult);

String value = m.matches() ? m.group(1) : null;
System.out.println("value: " + value);
```

Консоль:

```
vResult: {"Command":"101","ContractorGUID":"{29545D4D-7AC9-4FCB-9E5C-B7AF4D9A70B5}"}
value: {29545D4D-7AC9-4FCB-9E5C-B7AF4D9A70B5}
```